# Compare multiple items in a list of tuples and deleting tuples from the same list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

currently I'm analyzing subtitles with Python, so i downloaded a bunch of subtitles, but most series have multiple SRT-files for the same episode. I want to delete duplicates, therefore I wrote a regular expression that results in a list (re_results), which I formatted with *','.join(map(str, re_finds))* so I get a single string as my list element that only contains the series name, season and episode for each file. This will enable me to scan for similar strings, which then are a subtitle duplicate.

```
>>> re_duplicate = re.compile(r'^(.+)\s*-{1}\s*(\d+)x{1}(\d+)\s*-.*$')
>>> test_string = "CSI - 11x01 - Shock Waves.HDTV.FQM.en.srt"
>>> re_duplicate.findall(test_string)[0]
('CSI ', '11', '01')
>>> ','.join(map(str, re_duplicate.findall(test_string)[0]))
'CSI ,11,01'
```

(It doesn't matter what the string looks like, as long as it identifies the name, season and episode number.)
Since I'm only interested in the actual speech of the series I only want to keep the smallest file. The reason is that a smaller file will most likely not include the link where I got the subtitle, the creator, help for deaf people („[hears footsteps approaching]“ which isn't speech) and so on.

**The actual problem:**
To compare the files I created the following list of tuples: “subtitle_tuple_list”

Pattern: [('regex output as string', 'path to file inc. file name', filesize), ...]

```
[('CSI ,1,01', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x01 - Shock Waves.HDTV.FQM.en.srt', 53340), 
('CSI ,1,01', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x01 - Shock Waves.HDTV.LOL.en.srt', 52059), 
('CSI ,1,02', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x02 - Pool Shark.HDTV.en.srt', 62697), 
('CSI ,1,02', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x02 - Pool Shark.HDTV.LOL.en.srt', 61159), …]
```

What I want to do now (but can't):
Go through the list and compare the regex outputs, for each identical string compare the file size, delete all but the smallest one using the path and file name.

I know that one way is to get the regex output of the first tuple using:

```
[item[0] for item in subtitle_tuple_list]
```

Then I have to look up the regex output in the next tuple, if they match compare file size, delete the entry of bigger file from the list of tuples. If both are the same size keep the first one. Keep the soon to be deleted files in a separate list.
Do so until you get a new regex output, which is a different episode.
Repeat until only one file for each episode is left, which means the new list now contains all files to be deleted.
Delete all files mentioned in that list.

I have no idea how to write this part.

As an additional question: Is there a better way to delete unwanted subtitle files?

Comment: So, you're saying that, for example, regex `'CSI ,1,01'` yields two files with sizes `53340 and 52059`. Thus you should retain just the file with the smallest size which is `52059`?

Comment: Exactly. And your answer below works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` to collect all files by regex in lists. Then sort the lists by filesize:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('CSI ,1,01', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x01 - Shock Waves.HDTV.FQM.en.srt', 53340), 
('CSI ,1,01', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x01 - Shock Waves.HDTV.LOL.en.srt', 52059), 
('CSI ,1,02', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x02 - Pool Shark.HDTV.en.srt', 62697), 
('CSI ,1,02', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x02 - Pool Shark.HDTV.LOL.en.srt', 61159)]

dic = defaultdict(list)

for (reg, file, size) in data:
    dic[reg].append((file, size))

for key in dic:
    item=dic[key]
    item.sort(key=lambda t:t[1])
    print(item[0])
```

output:

```
('path_to_file\\CSI - 11x01 - Shock Waves.HDTV.LOL.en.srt', 52059)
('path_to_file\\CSI - 11x02 - Pool Shark.HDTV.LOL.en.srt', 61159)
```

Comment: Update: This is nor marked as the correct answer, since @AleksandrBorisov 's answer has a mistake in it. I checked quamrana 's output with some more files and didn't find an error. Hence the change to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

To filter the list as you want you can use pandas:

```
>>> data = [('CSI ,1,01', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x01 - Shock Waves.HDTV.FQM.en.srt', 53340), ('CSI ,1,01', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x01 - Shock Waves.HDTV.LOL.en.srt', 52059), ('CSI ,1,02', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x02 - Pool Shark.HDTV.en.srt', 62697), ('CSI ,1,02', 'path_to_file\CSI - 11x02 - Pool Shark.HDTV.LOL.en.srt', 61159)]

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df = df.groupby(0).min()
>>> df

                                                           1      2
0                                                                  
CSI ,1,01  path_to_file\CSI - 11x01 - Shock Waves.HDTV.FQ...  52059
CSI ,1,02  path_to_file\CSI - 11x02 - Pool Shark.HDTV.LOL...  61159
```

To convert it back to list:

```
df.values.tolist()
```

Comment: Update: Had to remove the correct answer tag. I noticed that this way pandas will asign the smallest file size to the first file mentioned. Compare the putput of this: `CSI - 11x01 - Shock Waves.HDTV.FQM.en.srt` is kept and assigned a file size of 52059, despite having a file size of 53340 in the original data set. It seems that `.min()` just keeps the smallest value instead of keeping the complete entry that has the smallest value.

Answer (score 0):

So let me get this right. you have many SRT for many CSI. and you want to arrange it such that there is **one** SRT per CSI episode.

Are all the files in the same directory? better yet can put sample files on git repo to look at? because there is a lot of variability to the solution depending how they are arranged and what their contents are.